# How to Concatenate a Variable and Literal in Char Pointer

Tags: c

I have a function that takes a char pointer as an arguments. I want to manually create the char pointer for the arguments. So, I have something like:

```
int a = 50;
char* command_args;
loop:
  command_args = "0 0 0 %d", a; //this is the main area where I neeed help. To clarify
                                //I'm trying to have my character array be set to "0 0 0 a" where 
                               //a is the variable holding an integer value
  functionCall(command_args);
  a += 5;
  command_args = " "; //I guess this would reset the char pointer?
```

I can't actually mess with the function itself so I need to do this with a char pointer.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. This pseudocode doesn't explain anything. Try formulating better. With examples.

Comment: What is the "comma a" supposed to do?

Comment: I think he's using a Pythonesque idiom there.  Which of course doesn't remotely work in C.

Comment: If you actually enter those command  line arguments, on a command line, they don't all appear in one string. Each argument will be in a separate string of `*argv[]` array.

Comment: Have a look at the `sprintf()` function.  Also, declare `command_args` as a char array of sufficient length, not as a pointer to a string literal, as string literals must not be modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use sprintf() to print a variable into a string. It works like printf() but the first argument is a pointer to some allocated memory (either static on the stack or via malloc).

```
char command_args[STATIC_BUFFER_SIZE];
sprintf(command_args, "0 0 0 %d", a);
```

You should size your buffer to hold at least the largest possible string representation of whatever datatype a is. Don't forget to account for the null terminator.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So could I then pass the command_args like so: function_Call(&command_args) ?

Comment: Arrays are converted to pointers when passed to a function. You wouldn't need the address operator &.  Just use func(command_args).

Comment: That worked great. Thanks a lot Matt!

Comment: You're welcome! Since the answer worked for you please remember to up vote it and accept it :)

Comment: Sure. Looks like it won't show my upvote since I'm a new user though. :(